# Jquery: How do you open links on the same page (i.e., click on links but the address bar link doesn't change)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I noticed the pages on jqGrid's demo pages (http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx) are opening links on the same page (i.e. the URL doesn't change when you click on that page's links even though the clickable URLs are different from the URL in the address bar).

Is there a Jquery plugin to do that?

Comment: Just remember that doing this will prevent users from being able to bookmark pages, search engines will have hard time indexing your site, and you will break the back/forward buttons of the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery's 
.ajax
.get
.post
.load
functions all can "load" data from whatever url you specify (on the same domain otherwise u hit the crossdomain block)

From there you have to manipulate the data with javascript however you want it on the page, 
with the exception of .load which you can use to load html directly into an html container like a div
example:

```
$("#MyContainer").load("/somepage.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). jQuery has different functions allowing you to fetch pages asynchronously and update the DOM: [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), ...